# DataFrame apply, ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 18 columns

Tags: python, dataframe, api, apply

When I use online Python editor, this code works.
I try to group rows and then to create nested JSON or dict but, when I read dataframe from S3 in visual studio in AWS - on
`apply(lambda x: x[['quantity','price','content_id']].to_dict('r'))` I have an error.

> ERROR
>
> [ERROR] ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 18 columns
> Traceback (most recent call

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

import pprint
import json 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize




json_str = '[{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":111,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":4.495,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6905,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":111,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":4.495,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6931,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":333,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":8.717,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":7093,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":777,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":8.717,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6688,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":111,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":4.495,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6896,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":777,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":8.717,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6493,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":444,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":4.495,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6905,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":111,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":4.495,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6931,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":333,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":8.717,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":7093,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":444,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":8.717,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6688,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":666,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":4.495,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6896,"content_id":"meow"},{"email":"mail","gen":"m","order_id":666,"product_group":"CUXHA","event_name":"DEU","value":53.867,"price":8.717,"event_date":"1843-01-01","quantity":6493,"content_id":"meow"}]'

data_list = json.loads(json_str)

df = json_normalize(data_list, None, None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(df)

jj = (df.groupby(['email','gen', 'event_name', 'value', 'product_group', 'event_date', 'order_id'], as_index=False)
.apply(lambda x: x[['quantity','price','content_id']].to_dict('r'))
.reset_index()
.rename(columns={0:'contents'}))
```

DataFrame

```
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   RangeIndex: 18 entries, 0 to 17
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   Data columns (total 15 columns):
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   # Column Non-Null Count Dtype
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   --- ------ -------------- -----
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   0 email 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   1 phone 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   2 fn 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   3 ln 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   4 gen 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   5 event_name 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   6 event_time 18 non-null int64
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   7 currency 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   8 value 18 non-null float64
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   9 product_group 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   10 event_date 0 non-null float64
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   11 order_id 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   12 content_id 18 non-null object
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   13 quantity 18 non-null float64
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   14 price 18 non-null float64
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   dtypes: float64(4), int64(1), object(10)
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   memory usage: 2.2+ KB
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   None
2021-02-26T15:36:39.637+01:00   Index(['email', 'phone', 'fn', 'ln', 'gen', 'event_name', 'event_time','currency', 'value', 'product_group', 'event_date', 'order_id','content_id', 'quantity', 'price'],
```

Comment: The aim _to create nested json or dict_ is too vague. How exactly shall the outcome look?

Answer (score 0):

This `ValueError` occurs as soon as there's more than one row in a group, hence you didn't encounter it with very simple test data in your *online python editor*. It doesn't occur if you drop the `, as_index=False`:

```
jj = df.groupby(['email','gen','event_name','value','product_group','event_date','order_id'])\
       .apply(lambda x: x[['quantity','price','content_id']].to_dict('records'))
```

`jj`

```
email  gen  event_name  value   product_group  event_date  order_id
mail   m    DEU         53.867  CUXHA          1843-01-01  111         [{'quantity': 6905, 'price': 4.495, 'content_id': 'meow'}, {'quantity': 6931, 'price': 4.495, 'content_id': 'meow'}, {'quantity': 6896, 'price': 4.495, 'content_id': 'meow'}, {'quantity': 6931, 'price': 4.495, 'content_id': 'meow'}]
                                                           333                                                                                                                             [{'quantity': 7093, 'price': 8.717, 'content_id': 'meow'}, {'quantity': 7093, 'price': 8.717, 'content_id': 'meow'}]
                                                           444                                                                                                                             [{'quantity': 6905, 'price': 4.495, 'content_id': 'meow'}, {'quantity': 6688, 'price': 8.717, 'content_id': 'meow'}]
                                                           666                                                                                                                             [{'quantity': 6896, 'price': 4.495, 'content_id': 'meow'}, {'quantity': 6493, 'price': 8.717, 'content_id': 'meow'}]
                                                           777                                                                                                                             [{'quantity': 6688, 'price': 8.717, 'content_id': 'meow'}, {'quantity': 6493, 'price': 8.717, 'content_id': 'meow'}]
dtype: object
```